# Distinctive characteristics of programming languages

Tags: programming-languages, syntax

Beyond the syntax of each language (e.g. print v. echo), what are some key distinctive characteristics to look out for to distinguish a programming language?

As a beginner in programming, I'm still confused between the strengths and weaknesses of each programming language and how to distinguish them beyond their aliases for common native functions. I think it's much easier to classify languages based on a set of distinctive characterstics e.g. OOP v. Functional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many thing that define a PL, here I'l list a few:

- Is it procedural, OO, imperative?
- Does it has strong type checking(C#, C++, Delphi) or dynamic(PHP, Pythong, JS)
- How are references handled? (Does it hide pointers like C#?)
- Does it require a runtime (C#, Java) or is it native to the OS(C, C++)
- Does it support threads (E.g Eiffel needs extra libraries for it)

There are may others like the prescense of garbage collectors, the handling of params, etc. The Eiffel language has an interesting feature which is Design By Contract, I haven't seen this on any other language(I think C# 4.0 has it now), but it can be pretty useful if well used.

I would recommend you to take a look on Bertrand Meyer's work to get a deeper understanding on how PL's work and the things that define them. Another thing that can define a PL is the interaction level with the system, this what makes the difference between low-level languages and high-level languages.

Hope I can help

Answer (score 4):

In a domain (imperative, functional, concatenative, term rewriting), sometimes its best to look at the presence or absence of any particular set of functionality. For example, for the main stream imperative.

1. First order functions
2. Closures
3. Built in classes, prototypical inheritance, or toolkit (Example: C++, Self/JavaScript, Lua/Perl)
4. Complex data types (more than array)
5. In-built concurrency primitives
6. Futures
7. Pass by values, pass by name, pass by reference or an combination thereof
8. Garbage collected or not? What kind?
9. Event-based
10. Interface based types, class based types, or no user types (Go, Java, Lua)

etc

Answer (score 0):

You can consider things like:

- Can you call functions?
- Can you pass functions to other functions?
- Can you create new functions? (In C you can pass function pointers to functions, but you cannot create new functions)
- Can you create new data types?
- Can you create new data types with functions that operate on them? (the typical basis for "OO" languages)
- Can you execute code that was not available at compile-time (using an `eval` function, maybe)?
- Must all types be known at compile-time?
- Are types available at run-time?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between *low-level* and *high-level* languages. (Even though "low" and "high" are relative terms.)

A high-level language will use an abstraction to hide details that low-level languages would expose to the user. For example, in Matlab or Python, you can initialize an N-dimensional array in a single command. Not so in C or assembly.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the strength of a language is given by how many things you can do with it; how fast and how easy can you accomplish the goals.

The weaknesses of a language are the sum of constraints (of various types) that you encounter while you try to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

There are many features that a programming language may support. Additionally these features aren't always mutually exclusive. For example OCaml and F# are both functional and object oriented. Also writing a list here of all the paradigms that a language can support would be exhaustive, however there is a book [Programming Language Pragmatics](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) that is a comprehensive treatment of many paradigms found in programming languages.

However, for me the important things I need to know when working with a language are the following:

- Is it dynamically or statically typed
- Is it a typed language, and if it is typed is strong or weak?
- Is it garbage collected
- Does it support pass by value or pass by reference semantics or both?
- Does it support first order functions (i.e. can functions be treated as variables)
- Is it object-oriented
- Polymorphism. Is it parametric or ad-hoc.
- How expressive is the type system (i.e. can I create non-leaky abstractions)
- Overloaded methods
- Generics (templates)
- Exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

- [Type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) (typed vs untyped, statically vs dynamically typed, weakly and strongly typed).
- [Supported paradigms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm) (procedural, object-oriented, functional, logic, multi).
- [Default implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_implementation) (compiler vs interpreter vs JIT-compiler).
- Memory management ([manual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_memory_management) vs automatic ([reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) or [GC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29))).
- Intended [domain of use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_domain) (number crunching, prototyping, scripting, DSL, ...).
- Generation ([1GL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-generation_programming_language), [2GL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-generation_programming_language), [3GL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-generation_programming_language), [4GL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language), [5GL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth-generation_programming_language)).
- Used natural language (English vs [Non-English-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English-based_programming_languages)). However, it's about syntax.

General remark: many of this classification scheme are not comprehensive and are not that good. And links are mostly at Wikipedia. So be aware.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider other characteristics such as:

- Strong vs weak and static vs dynamic typing, support for generic typing
- How memory is handled (is it abstracted or do you have direct control over your data, pass by ref vs pass by value)
- Compiled vs interpreted vs a bit of both
- The forms of user-defined types available... classes, structures, tuples, lists etc.
- Whether threading facilities are inbuilt or you need to turn to external libraries
- Facility for generative coding... C++ template metaprogramming is a form of this
- In the case of OOP, single vs multi inheritance, interfaces, anonymous/inner classes etc.
- Whether a language is multi-paradigm (i.e. C# and its support for functional programming)
- Availability of reflection
- The verbosity of a language or the amount of 'syntactic sugar'... e.g. C++ is quite verbose when it comes to iterating over a vector. Java is quite succinct when anonymous inner classes are used for event-handling. Python's list comprehensions save a lot of typing.